# How does expo push notification token work? ExponentPushToken[XYC]

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

In expo SDK36, I target iOS and Android.

I am trying in development the push notification, on Android device, my device have : `ExponentPushToken[XYZ]` and my iOS device have `ExponentPushToken[ABC]`

- Are those generated token unique?
- Are they generated client side ?
- Can I safely add them to my database to identify my devices?
- Will all the release channel (staging/preprod/prod) use the same token for each devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All tokens are unique **but** a new token is generated each time you reinstall the app, so each builds (probably with store updates too) so you have to handle that. You can do something like deleting all tokens at each new build.

Storing tokens in you DB is, as i know, the only way. It's up to you to secure their access.

In Android build, you need a firebase api key to handle notifications. See https://docs.expo.io/push-notifications/using-fcm/

Comment: So a token will work on all stages, staging, preproduction and production, correct?

Comment: Yeah of course, you just need a firebase api key to receive notifs on Android

Comment: I did not had a firebase api key and never read about firebase in the expo documentation, I am able to send push notification in development using the [expo notificaiton tool](https://expo.io/notifications), I feel confused, can you explain a bit more that firebase part?

Comment: You only need it in a Android build. it's pretty simple to implement. See https://docs.expo.io/push-notifications/using-fcm/

Comment: How to upload server credentials on expo? I am reading [here](https://docs.expo.io/push-notifications/using-fcm/#uploading-server-credentials) and within my expo UI, I cannot see any gear icon on my project dashboard...

Comment: In your Firebase console, the gear is in top left right to Dashboard or Project overview. Then Cloud Messaging tab. Your server key is here. Then run the comand in expo and you're done

Comment: Thanks I found it. I have well configured the `google-services.json`, I am now stuck to step 4, where google wait for the app to respond (and it didn't it still unconfigured).  I have never released an application to the play store, should I test and finish the configuration for the messaging after releasing both iOS and Android app?

Comment: What do you mean by configuring the `google-services.json` ? Just download it from your firebase console and that's it. Is your project running ? Maybe you have to close it or conversely, if not running, try launch to launch it, i'm not sure. To test juste make a build and install it on an Android

Answer (score 12):

The accepted answer has some out of date information (as of 9/3/21), so here's the latest.

Expo Tokens are generated on the Client when you call `Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()` (Notifications is an expo library).

This Token will remain valid EVEN IF the app is updated. Per [Expo's documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/faq/):

> The ExpoPushToken will remain the same across app upgrades, and ejecting to the bare workflow. On iOS, it will also remain the same even after uninstalling the app and reinstalling (on Android, this results in the push token changing)

You should store this token on your Server DB. They are unique identifiers for sending a push notification to a specific device. From [Expo's overview](https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/push-notifications-setup/) on push notifications:

> If push notifications are mail, then the ExpoPushToken is the user's address

Regarding your question about different tokens for different release channels, for Android, there is no difference. For iOS, there will be a different token for Sandbox vs. Production. You should [pass an argument](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/#getexpopushtokenasyncoptions-expotokenoptions-expopushtoken) to `getExpoPushTokenAsync` that indicates that you are in Sandbox

Answer (score 4):

in order to send  push notifications with expo, we need to get "expo push token" which is unique for each device. Token is an identifies the device so all the release channel (staging/preprod/prod) use the same token for each device.  whenever user logins, we ask for notifications and permissions to get expo push token for the device. So when user logs in "initNotification" function gets fired.

Let's say in a multiplayer game app, a player wants to invite the player1, in the app, we send a request to expo to send a notification to player1. expo first will send you "expo push token".this token is going to be saved into database. when we create a table for our push tokens in DB, this table will have One-To-Many relation with the Players. one player can have "many tokens" because one player can log in using multiple devices and each device will have its unique token. Player instance will hold an array of tokens.

When you send a request to Expo, Expo will return you answer. Either an error message or a "ticket". when we get a successful response from expo, response has `ticketId`. if response has an error for the token, we remove the token from the DB becuase for certain type of errors we need to stop sending multiple notifications.

This `ticketId` will be stored in the DB. because when we send request to expo and expo sends back its response, even if response is successful it does not mean that notification is received by the device. it just means that the expo received your request to send notification. Expo will then send that notification to Apple or Google and then Apple and Google will send the notification to devices. Using the "ticketId" saved in database, we make a follow up request to expo to check the response that expo received from Apple or Google. if notification was not sent and you try to send notification again, Apple or Google might ban you. that is why we have to remove the tokens from the db. also remove the tickets that handled.

whenever user logs out, we need to remove the token from the db.

Comment: hi, i have a question. When user first downloads the app they accept notification permission and a expo token is stored in my db, when user logs out that token gets deleted from my db. My question is what if the user decides to close the notification settings on their phone while the token still exists in db? The notification does not get sent but what should happen to the token? should i leave it in db or delete it?